# Why don't we need to do the error calculations for all the repeated measurements?

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis, statistics

> This is from  *John Taylor- "An Introduction to Error Analysis"*
>   The passage asks us to calculate the uncertainty of refractive index n using Snell's Law
>   $$\sin i=n \sin r$$
>   The fractional uncertainty in $n$ is the quadratic sum of those in $\sin i$ and $\sin r$:
>   $$\frac{\delta n}{n}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\delta \sin i}{\sin i} \right)^2+\left(\frac{\delta \sin r}{\sin r}\right)^2}$$
>   The calculation is then carried out as shown in the table below
>   [image]
>   And then in the last paragraph, the author mentioned that
>
> > "If you repeat an experiment like this one several times, the error calculations can become tedious if you do them for each repetition. You should recognize, **however, that you almost never need to do the error calculations for all the repetitions; if you find the uncertainties in $n$ corresponding to the smallest and largest values of $i$ (and possibly a few intermediate values), then these uncertainties suffice for most purposes."**

I don't understand why don't we need to do the error calculations for all the repetitions, since the $\frac{\delta n}{n}$ values look quite different for each repetition in the table? And what does he mean by **"if you find the uncertainties in $n$ corresponding to the smallest and largest values of $i$"**?

Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what the author means is that if you had values $i=30^\circ$ and  $i=19^\circ$ then you could make an estimate of the error as being about $7\%$ as midway between $9\%$ and $5\%$.

The mention of intermediate values is there to make the interpolation of the error of intermediate values more accurate.

---

Note that in this example you could make the error calculation easier by noting that $\delta(\sin i)\approx \delta i \cos i $ and so $\dfrac{\delta ( \sin i)}{\sin i }\approx \delta i \cot i$ where $\delta i$ is in radians.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason you shouldn't do the error calculation for each measurement - especially if you enter the measurements into a spreadsheet.

However, I think all the book is getting at is that there is a clear relationship between the value of the angle and the size of its contribution to the error in $n$.

If $y = \sin \theta$, and there is a (small) error in $\theta$, then it is the case that
$$\frac{\Delta y}{y} \simeq \frac{\cos \theta\ \Delta\theta}{\sin \theta} = \frac{\Delta\theta}{\tan \theta}$$

Thus as $\theta$ increases, the percentage error decreases, as you see in the table.

Or, wrapping up the whole expression for $n$ and assuming $i$ and $r$ are measured with the same precision $\Delta \theta$
$$ \frac{\Delta n}{n}\simeq \Delta\theta   \left( \frac{\cos^2 i}{\sin^2 i} + \frac{\cos^2 r}{\sin^2 r}\right)^{1/2}$$

A bit of trigonometry and use of Snell's law$^{*}$ shows you this is a decreasing function of $i$.
$$\frac{\Delta n}{n}\simeq \Delta\theta\left(2\cot^2 i +\frac{n^2-1}{\sin^2 i}\right)^{1/2}$$
Of course, we don't know $n$ when we start the experiment, so all this shows is that the percentage error in $n$ should get smaller smoothly as $i$ increases.

$^{*}$ Replace $\sin^2 r$ with $\sin^2 i/n^2$ and $\cos^2 r$ with $1 - \sin^2 i/n^2$.
$$  \frac{\Delta n}{n}\simeq \Delta\theta   \left( \frac{1-\sin^2 i}{\sin^2 i} + \frac{1-\sin^2 i/n^2}{\sin^2 i/n^2}\right)^{1/2}$$
$$\frac{\Delta n}{n}\simeq \Delta\theta   \left( \frac{1-\sin^2 i +n^2 -\sin^2 i}{\sin^2 i}\right)^{1/2}$$
$$\frac{\Delta n}{n}\simeq \Delta\theta   \left( \frac{2 - 2\sin^2 i + (n^2 -1)}{\sin^2 i}\right)^{1/2}
$$$$\frac{\Delta n}{n}\simeq \Delta\theta\left(2\cot^2 i +\frac{n^2-1}{\sin^2 i}\right)^{1/2}$$

Comment: Hi, may I know how do you get to the last expression?